# How to fetch emails from my Gmail Inbox that are in a time bound IOS SDK?

Tags: ios, email, gmail-api

I want to fetch my emails from my Gmail inbox.As i came to know that I can use Google Search API:

[("GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q="in:sent after:2014/01/01 before:2014/01/30"
")](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering).

I am successfully able to fetch emails in paging manner using

```
 let batchQuery = GTLRBatchQuery ()
        for message in labelsResponse.messages! {
            let query = GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesGet.query(withUserId: "me", identifier: message.identifier!)
            query.format = kGTLRGmailFormatFull
            batchQuery.addQuery(query)

        }
        self.service.shouldFetchNextPages = true
        self.service.executeQuery(batchQuery,
                                  delegate: self,
                                  didFinish: #selector(self.displayMessageDetailsList(_:finishedWithObject:error:)))
```

but I do not know how to make query for Google Message search API and execute that query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesGet`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GoogleAPIClientForREST/1.0.2/Classes/GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesGet.html) which AFAIK, only gets a specific (one) mail.

You should instead use [`GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesList`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GoogleAPIClientForREST/1.0.1/Classes/GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesList.html), where you are able to actually use the [`q`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GoogleAPIClientForREST/1.0.1/Classes/GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesList.html#//api/name/q) property to [search messages, the same way like in the RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering):

> @property (copy, nullable) NSString *q
>
> Discussion
>
> Only return messages matching the specified query. Supports the same query format as the Gmail search box. For example, “from:someuser\@example.com rfc822msgid: is:unread”.
>
> Declared In GTLRGmailQuery.h

Comment: Hi Al i wrote this query.q = "in:inbox after:2016/01/01 before:2017/01/1" to fetch mails with in date but can u tell what query i should write to fetch those mails with in date and has a word e.g "bank" in their content ...

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use the search for the body (see [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/vuvd-ju7vfw/LGvfnLdSWbMJ), but you could do it in the title with `contains`.